# How to use save button for saving information from different Tab in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

in my app I have a Main Activity that contains tabhost with two tabs.
user should fill the information in these two tabs and press save button in main Activity and data should be save!

what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a ViewPager linked to a TabLayout, very easy by this way

Comment: thank you for your response, but can you explain more. in main page that contain ViewPager I should access to the component in each tab!

Comment: I use public method in each activity that I call them for tab, so I can access to the component(EditText and etc)  in main activity. if there is easier way, I would be happy to tell me.